# Datastore operation timed out during excel file generation

Tags: python, excel, google-app-engine, xlwt, xlutils

I'm generating an excel file using xlwt and store it on datastore as blob property. But during the generation got this error `"Timeout: The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable."`.

I have noticed that using xlutils we can update the exsisting files. I'm planning to do something like this, first time i will craete the file with half of my data and using another task will complete the file creation.

is there any better way to do this ?

Here is my current code:

```
from xlwt import *
wb = Workbook()
ws0 = wb.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

style = XFStyle()
style.font.name = 'Tahoma'   

currency_style = XFStyle()
currency_style.num_format_str = '$#,##0.00'       

ws0.write(0, 0, 'Col 1', style)
ws0.write(0, 1, 'Col 2', style)
ws0.write(0, 2, 'Col 3', style)
ws0.write(0, 3, 'Col 4', style)
rx = 1

for each in db_result:                
      ws0.write(rx, 0, each.col1, style)
      ws0.write(rx, 1, each.col2, style)
      ws0.write(rx, 2, each.col3, style)

      try:
          ws0.write(rx, 3, round(float(each.col4), 2), currency_style)
      except:
          ws0.write(rx, 3, each.col4, style)

      rx = rx + 1                
      db.delete(each)

buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
wb.save(buffer)
contents = buffer.getvalue()

f = myfile()
f.name = 'File 1'
f.file = db.Blob(contents)
f.put()
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a timeout issue where your code runs for longer then the timeout you could use a task instead, which gives you a 10 minute timeout instead of 60 seconds: [Background work with the deferred library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred)

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

  def do_something_expensive(a, b, c=None):
      logging.info("Doing something expensive!")
      # Do your work here

  # Somewhere else
  deferred.defer(do_something_expensive, "Hello, world!", 42, c=True)
```

So wrap your program up in a function you can pass to the defer method. Or look at using some of the other options like backends:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/

> App engine Backends are instances of your application that are exempt from
>   request deadlines and have access to more memory (up to 1GB) and CPU
>   (up to 4.8GHz) than normal instances. They are designed for
>   applications that need faster performance, large amounts of
>   addressable memory, and continuous or long-running background
>   processes. Backends come in several sizes and configurations, and are
>   billed for uptime rather than CPU usage.